# asp:CheckBoxList with parents

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

Is there somewhere an example of make use of a asp.net CheckBoxList 
with parent?

how can i achieve this.

its a standaard asp.net Control but ive never seen it working with parents.
maybe JQuery is an option?

[image]

Its a CheckBoxList not a dropdownlist that different

Comment: Working with parent as in? Can you clarify with some example or code snippet?

Comment: See image i posted thats an asp.net Checkbox Control.

Comment: It looks like a TreeView with Checkboxes?

Comment: Ye something like that but i want to do it with the asp.net control CheckboxList if it is possible

Comment: Though I am not sure of solution with CheckboxList but a treeview will do for hierarchical data just by setting a property `treeView.CheckBoxes = true'

Comment: Ye im trying that aswell ty can ya make a answher of it ? i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not sure of a solution for your case with CheckboxList but a treeview should do for hierarchical data display by setting a property `treeView.CheckBoxes = true`, to show checkboxes in front of the nodes.

[TreeView with Checkboxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178259.aspx) - MSDN documentation for reference.

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654295/working-with-checkbox-in-treeview-asp-net) may also help you.